# Error while debugging native and java-app on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, native, lldb

While developing an app for Android, I was able to debug native and managed code. But, once I disconnected the cable while in debug session and I close manually on the smartphone the app, it becomes undebugeable again:

```
java.lang.Throwable: LLDB server not found
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:137)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask.newSessionStarter(ConnectLLDBTask.java:360)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask.access$200(ConnectLLDBTask.java:91)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask$3.createDebugProcess(ConnectLLDBTask.java:598)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.testing.CidrLauncher.startDebugProcess(CidrLauncher.java:29)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.CidrCommandLineState.startDebugProcess(CidrCommandLineState.java:30)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.CidrRunner$1.start(CidrRunner.java:63)
    at com.intellij.xdebugger.impl.XDebuggerManagerImpl.startSession(XDebuggerManagerImpl.java:205)
    at com.intellij.xdebugger.impl.XDebuggerManagerImpl.startSession(XDebuggerManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.CidrRunner.startDebugSession(CidrRunner.java:56)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask.launchCidrDebugger(ConnectLLDBTask.java:628)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.ConnectLLDBTask.launchDebugger(ConnectLLDBTask.java:296)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.ConnectDebuggerTask.lambda$perform$0(ConnectDebuggerTask.java:90)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil$12.run(UIUtil.java:3098)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:755)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:704)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:391)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

the before stacktrace is from Android Studio after launching debug, it appears an `!` at bottom right.

Then, the result in Debug window is:

```
Now Launching Native Debug Session
Error while starting native debug session: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

I am not able to debug now! That is happening to me and I am able to fix it by following these steps:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Delete `c:\Users\<USER>\{.android, .gradle, .AndroidStudio3.3}`
3. Delete `<ProjectFolder>\{.gradle, .idea}`
4. Delete tmp files in AppData.
5. Open and re-debug app.

**I found a faster way to temporally solve it by deleting two directories:**

1. Close Android Studio
2. Delete `c:\Users\<USER>\.lldb`
3. Delete `c:\Users\<USER>\.AndroidStudio3.4\system\tmp\*`
4. Re-open Android Studio
5. Now you should be able to debug again

Comment: Do you have LLDB?

Comment: Yes I have LLDB.

Comment: Hahaha, it makes me laugh because it is logic that I have (not) LLDB due to my description and error of Android Studio.

Comment: that last part (faster way) helped me, you should post it as an answer

Comment: Yes, I should, but I prefer someone find a better solution because it is always breaking and restoring the deleted files with Android Studio is very slow... so, is it still a bug?

Comment: In my case it was because the device was connected to PC in "charge only" mode.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same exception `Error while starting native debug session: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException`

Then following helps me. Check if this can helps you...

[image]

Or open run configurations
[image]

Then check this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was uninstalling the apk and reinstalling it (using the debugger). Android Studio version 2021.1.1 for Ubuntu 18.04